# How to inject a logging statement before every catch block in java

Tags: java, jboss, code-injection, aop

I initially started with Aspect Oriented Programming using JBoss , and have implemented their code injection for - Before and After the method gets called  and After the Method Throws an Exception.
Now i want to know how do we inject code within the method ? I want to inject a Logging statement before every catch block gets executed , How do we do that using java ?

Comment: You could use a byte code manipulation library like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) and [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/).

Comment: I'm not sure about jboss but in java you just add the code, it's almost by definition. That's the whole purpose of the catch block

Comment: @Typo No, he's asking about Aspect Oriented Programming, which will automatically do things like this.  If you mean "How do you do that using Java?  A: You don't." well, true, but it's kind of a snarky answer.

Comment: @Elliot Thanks for the quick reply ,The problem i am facing is that i have an already working code which i am not supposed to change . This code generates and Throws Exceptions back and also handles them internally without any Logging , so i need to inject the logging statements ! Any idea where i need to start for this ?

Comment: @KausthubNaarayan You cannot "inject" logging statements; the closest you can do is to modify the bytecode in your catch blocks... do not expect it to be easy.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 
 
Will Aspect oriented Programming using AspectJ something like that can help ? Sorry to ask these questions as i am a beginner , and Thanks for taking time to answer

Comment: @KausthubNaarayan If you could add an aspect then you could modify the code, and I don't think there's a way to cross-cut concerns with-in a method.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know much about JBoss AOP, but in any case you can use AspectJ because it features a `handler()` pointcut.

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class Application {
    public static void throwRandomException() throws TimeoutException, IOException, NamingException {
        switch (new Random().nextInt(5)) {
            case 0: throw new TimeoutException("too late, baby");
            case 1: throw new FileNotFoundException("file.txt");
            case 2: throw new IOException("no read permission");
            case 3: throw new NullPointerException("cannot call method on non-existent object");
            case 4: throw new NamingException("unknown name");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try { throwRandomException(); }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {}
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
            catch (TimeoutException e) {}
            catch (IOException e) {}
            catch (NamingException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class CaughtExceptionLogger {
    @Before("handler(*) && args(e)")
    public void logCaughtException(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Exception e) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
handler(catch(TimeoutException)) -> too late, baby
handler(catch(FileNotFoundException)) -> file.txt
handler(catch(NamingException)) -> unknown name
handler(catch(TimeoutException)) -> too late, baby
handler(catch(NamingException)) -> unknown name
handler(catch(NamingException)) -> unknown name
handler(catch(NullPointerException)) -> cannot call method on non-existent object
handler(catch(FileNotFoundException)) -> file.txt
handler(catch(FileNotFoundException)) -> file.txt
handler(catch(NullPointerException)) -> cannot call method on non-existent object
```

Comment: thanks kriegaex , this is exactly what i had wanted to do !

Comment: in my example its not working, is there any other config needs.

Comment: @Zigri2612: I cannot say anything intelligent about your problem, not seeing your code. "My example is not working" is not a particularly good basis for diagnosis. How about preparing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and opening a new question here?

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for that answer, can we also have aspects like this one on specific method statements? For example, if I have a System.out.println() in the method throwRandomException(), and I want an aspect to be triggered on its call.

Comment: Yes, but that is a completely different topic. So please do not hijack this question, but (a) search for your problem first (it should have been answered multiple times here) or, if (a) fails, create a new one (should not be necessary in this case). P.S.: `cflow()` is your friend. ;-)